# Android - Display SQLite database query in a specific timeframe

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an app to keep track the time of phone usage.
The problem is, i need to display the time usage just in a day. 
for example i need to display from database the time my apps used only from 12.00 am - 11.59 pm
and the time need to be reset in the next day.

here is my code:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_APPTIME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE app_time (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "packageName TEXT UNIQUE," +
            "appName TEXT," +
            "elapsedTime INTEGER )";
```

and here is the query to retrieve the time

```
public List<AppTime> getAllAppTime() {
    List<AppTime> appTimes = new LinkedList<AppTime>();

    // build query
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_APPTIME + " WHERE " + KEY_TIME + " > 0";

    // get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

i need to display the elapsedTime from 12.00 a.m until 11.59 pm daily and reset the time in the next day.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways i can suggest

1. If you are ready to modify the app_time table, you can add a date column to keep track of the day. In this case you can show the user a history based on dates. Your query will need to have a date filter and there is no need to reset the database. (you might still want to remove entries older than 60days just to keep the database size under limit)

The table can be modified as below

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_APPTIME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE app_time (" +
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "packageName TEXT UNIQUE," +
        "appName TEXT," +
        "elapsedTime INTEGER, " + 
        "dateCol VARCHAR(50) )";
```

Add these two methods

```
public static String getCurrentDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}

public static String getDateFor(int date, int month, int year) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); // month starts from 0
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Then in you query you can access the rows for a particular day like this

```
// build query
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_APPTIME + " WHERE dateCol = '" + getCurrentDate() + "'";
```

2. You can use AlarmManager to be executed at 12:00AM everyday, where you can execute a service to reset the timers. [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: i could try the first way that u suggest. could you teach me how?

Comment: i tried your code and it runs perfectly but the results of the list is empty. what to do?

Comment: while inserting records have you put the date?? Extract the database or try viewing all records without any where clause?